# How do you say “He is quite beneficial to his elder brothers when he attends their meetings.”

Tags: constructions

How do you say “He is quite beneficial to his elder brothers when he attends their meetings.”?

All I have gotten so far is “Il est passablement bénéfique à ses frères aînés quand il va à leurs réunions.”

I’m unsure about “passablement”.

Answer (score 2):

> Il est extrêmement [utile](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/utile)/d'une aide inestimable à ses frères
> aînés lorsqu'il participe à leur rencontre.
>  Il aide énormément ses
> frères aînés lorsqu'il participe à leur rencontre.
>  Il [se rend
> très utile](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_rendre_utile) à ses frères aînés lorsqu'il participe à leur
> rencontre.
> Ça fait vraiment du bien à ses frères aînés quand il va les voir.
> [really does them some good/makes them feel better]
> Lorsqu'il participe à leur rencontre, ça leur [to them] est vraiment [bénéfique](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C3%A9n%C3%A9fique). [be benefical]

If *quite* is not about the highest degree but rather [moderately](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/quite/605503), some of these adverbs may be replaced by the colloquial [*pas mal*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pas_mal) i.e. *pas mal utile* etc..

Comment: Hello @ ZéhontéeBonteuse . Is there a reason why you didn’t use the adjective bénéfique?

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteyse May I ask why you think it didn’t fit the bill?

Comment: I understand, thank you. So the part of idkidkid’s sentence which say “Il est passablement bénéfique à ses frères aînés...” is a possibility then?

Comment: Oh I understand, thank you again. So that part of the sentence is grammatically correct but it’s not idiomatic to you. Understood.

Comment: @jlliagre “He is somewhat beneficial to...” is the meaning the sentence  “He is quite beneficial to...” is conveying. It is written in the dictionary written by Oxford Languages  that one of the definitions of the word quite is “ to a certain or fairly significant extent or degree; fairly.”. I’m sorry as I see I should have provided more context.